# King Agag held captive for one night - Source?

Tags: tanach, amalek

Where specifically does it say that King Shaul held King Agag alive as captive for a single night before Shmuel killed him?

(Looking for something that specifies it was only one night)

Comment: It's implied by the sequence of events in Shmuel I 15. He captures Agag, keeps him alive, Hashem speaks to Shmuel through the night, Shmuel goes to rebuke Shaul in the morning, and then Shaul executes Agag. See also: https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=2967

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33844/6592

Answer (score 2):

Ohr HaChaim writes: "Megillah 13 reveals that during the night that Saul kept Agag prisoner he succeeded in impregnating a woman who perpetuated his seed throughout the ages." [On Numbers 24:7]  "The" night implies it's one night.

Comment: Do you know where the part is where it says he changed into a sheep to do this?

Comment: @CuriousYid http://tinyurl.com/3bp6tvc3 - http://tinyurl.com/3z8n78vn - -http://tinyurl.com/muv829xd and other places